# RxJava Observable to generate repeated events when button is down

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-binding

I'm trying to write an observable that would generate repeated events while the user holds down a view. My code below works well, but only the first time (e.g. if the user presses the button again, nothing happens). Can you please advise what am I doing wrong and what is best practice for this?

```
val touches = RxView.touches(previousButton)
touches
        .filter({ event -> event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN })
        .flatMap({
            Observable.interval(500, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .takeUntil(touches.filter({event -> event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP}))
        }).subscribe({ println("down") })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `RxView.touches` observable cannot exist for more than 1 source. This means when the subscription inside of the `flatMap` happens it breaks the original subscription used to trigger the `flatMap`, making it never occur again.

There are two possible ways around this:

1. Use `.publish(...)` to share the source of events instead of using `touches`.
2. Map the events into a `Boolean` on/off observable, then `switchMap` the appropriate actions based on the current value of the observable.

1.

```
touches.publish { src ->
    src.filter(...)
       .flatMap {
           Observable.interval(...)
                     .takeUntil(src.filter(...))
       }
}
```

2.

```
touches.filter {
           it.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
                or it.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
       }
       .map { it.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN }
       .distinctUntilChanged() // Avoid repeating events
       .switchMap { state ->
           if (state) {
               Observable.interval(...)
           } else {
               Observable.never()
           }
       }
```

Comment: I'm going to accept it since the second method worked for me. I am curious though why I couldn't get the first one tow work, even with autoconnect? Here is the code that did NOT work:
```touches.publish().autoConnect(2).let { sharedTouches ->
            sharedTouches.filter({ event -> event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN })
                .flatMap({
                    Observable.interval(....)
                            .takeUntil(sharedTouches.filter({ event -> event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP }))
                }).subscribe(...)
        }
```

Comment: Because it would only subscribe after 2 inner subscriptions, but the secondary subscription only happens after the first subscription emits something. So it ends up in a deadlock waiting for a subscription that never happens.